# How do you size an empty input in FFmpeg to match an existing video stream?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am trying to create a colored box of a matching size to my first input video source (-i) and stack them right next to each other.

```
-i movie.mov -filter_complex \
  "color=c=black,scale=w=300:h=-1[c_s]; \
  [c_s][0:v]scale2ref[c]; \
  [0:v][c]hstack=shortest=1:inputs=2[combined]" \
 -map "[combined]" out.mov
```

I get this error though:

```
[Parsed_vstack_12 @ 0x7f94b0d0a120] Input 1 width 3840 does not match input 0 width 600.
Error configuring complex filters.
```

How do I fix the size differences?

Answer (score 1):

Your command uses hstack but your error shows vstack. I assume that's from a different command. Anyway, use

```
-i movie.mov -filter_complex \
  "color=c=black[c_s]; \
  [c_s][0:v]scale2ref[c][v]; \
  [c]setsar=1[cr]; \
  [v][cr]hstack=shortest=1:inputs=2[combined]" \
 -map "[combined]" out.mov
```

---

Although, for this specific requirement, you can just pad the video.

```
-i movie.mov -vf pad=2*iw:ih:color=black out.mov
```